# How to use protocol extension to provide auto-generated identifier for classes?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to provide an auto-generated identifier for each custom UITableViewCell subclass. I try the following code, but the compiler says

> type 'T' has no member 'autoReuseIdentifier'

```
protocol AutoReusable: class {
    static var autoReuseIdentifier: String { get }
}

extension AutoReusable {
    static var autoReuseIdentifier: String {
        return "\(self)"
    }
}

extension UITableViewCell: AutoReusable {}

func printClassName<T: UITableViewCell>(type type: T.Type) {
    print(T.autoReuseIdentifier)
}
```

It's okay to implement the protocol in an extension for UITableViewCell, but I prefer to implement it in a protocol extension. How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic `T` in `printClassName(...)` does not know that it conforms to `AutoReusable` protocol (even if you, as the developer, knows that `UITableViewCell` does so), it only knows that it is a `UITableViewCell` och `UITableViewCell` subclass object.

You could redeem this by adding a `... where T: AutoReusable>` in the generic type constraint of `printClassName(...)`

```
func printClassName<T: UITableViewCell where T: AutoReusable>(type type: T.Type) {
    print(T.autoReuseIdentifier)
}
```

A more common implementation of `printClassName(...)` would be, however, to constraint `T` to the protocol `AutoReusable`, rather than let `printClassName` be a function specifically for `UITableViewCell` objects (subclass objects)

```
func printClassName<T: AutoReusable>(type type: T.Type) {
    print(T.autoReuseIdentifier)
}
```

This generic function can then be called from any type conforming to `AutoReusable`, whereas you can control the default implementation of `autoReuseIdentifier` by different extensions to the protocol `AutoReusable`. E.g., as a complete example:

```
protocol AutoReusable: class {
    static var autoReuseIdentifier: String { get }
}

/* Default implementation */
extension AutoReusable {
    static var autoReuseIdentifier: String {
        return "\(self)"
    }
}

/* Default implementation specifically for UITableViewCell (and subclasses) */
extension AutoReusable where Self: UITableViewCell {
    static var autoReuseIdentifier: String {
        return "\(self) (UITableViewCell)"
    }
}

/* Generic function invokable by any class type conforming to printClassName */
func printClassName<T: AutoReusable>(type type: T.Type) {
    print(T.autoReuseIdentifier)
}

/* Example setup */
extension UITableViewCell: AutoReusable { }
class Foo : AutoReusable { }
class MyCell : UITableViewCell {}

/* Example usage */
let foo = Foo()
let bar = MyCell()

printClassName(type: foo.dynamicType) // Foo
printClassName(type: bar.dynamicType) // MyCell (UITableViewCell)
```